# How are these three equations that are rewritten equal eachother?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

[image]

This question has been driving me insane for about a day now. I cannot figure how these two are equal and I understand the laws of logarithms decently. Regardless, when I try to show equality in a calculator between these three functions expressed in the gray; I get different answers every time. So does this boil down a calculation error on my end or is there more going on here that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Comment: I should comment my biggest struggle is with the x^log(x) and e^(log^2(x)).

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! The *definition* of $a^b$ $\, (a>0)$ is that it is $\;\mathrm e^{b\ln a}$.

Comment: @Bernard This is extremely helpful, however I love to see things play out so I entered five in my calculation for x in each equation and they appear to be different. Does this simply me I am calculating wrong? I have tried multiple styles for inputting the equations and they all pan out to the same answer.

Comment: @Bernard So I figured out my problem. To clarify I believe I was incorrect due to the fact that once in base e the "log" must be "ln" correct?

Comment: That's right; if your calculator has a "ln" button then that is the one to use for log base e. On such a calculator the "log" button typically means $\log_{10}$ (base 10 logarithm).

Comment: In theory, yes. But the old name was `log`, it it's always used for the multibranch complex logarithm, and I tend to use `log` when there's a `n` integer variable involved (sequences and series). For instance $\ln n$ is rather confusional, in my opinion.

Comment: @David K: And in complexity theory, it's generally the log to the base $2$.

Comment: @Bernard Sure, that just underscores the fact that you need to remember "who you're talking to" when using the name "log" for a function. In this particular case, however, we're "talking to" Austin's calculator.

Comment: thank you both @Bernard and David K I understand now and formulated my own answer for this question unless Bernard would like to do so and I will accept it. My answer I posted was more of the answer that I explicitly wanted however I was only able to reach it thank to Bernard.

Comment: By the way, Austin, it's good you attempted to replicate the formula with examples in actual numbers. It's a good way to check your understanding (or as a check whether the formula you came up with in an exercise is correct).

Comment: I don'understand the presence of the last line with the derivation operation. How is it connected to the first line ?

Comment: @JeanMarie It is simply a snipping of a step by step breakdown of the derivation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that in the image they are appearing equal is a bit of a misrepresentation for me. Following the help of @Bernard the equation actually is not e^(log(x))*(log(x)) but more rather x^log(x) = e^(log(x) * ln(x)) due to the base e.

Answer (score 0):

Taking $x=5$ ... plug these into your calculator
\begin{eqnarray*}
5 \hat{} (\ln 5 ) =13.33 \cdots \\
e(\ln ( 5 \hat{}(\ln 5 ))) =13.33 \cdots \\
e((\ln 5) \hat{}2 ) =13.33 \cdots \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: $e(\ln(...)$ should be written $\exp(\ln(...$

Comment: It is $e( \cdots)$ on my calculator ... I have a OX-240 $\ddot \smile $ ... anyway I think Austin has resolved the problem between $\log$ and $ \ln $.

Comment: My remark intended only to stick to the most used convention.